# Javascript for loop array only shows end array

Tags: javascript

When I run the program only the end array displays from what I have gathered it is a for loop closure problem. I have tried many things from looking at earlier posts but still have not managed to find a solution.

Thx
Pav

```js
var words = 
        [
    ['how', 'are', 'you', 'today?'],
    ['what', 'would', 'you', 'like', 'for', 'breakfast?'],
    ['what', 'would', 'you', 'like', 'for', 'tea?']
];

var correctInput = [
    ['how are you today?'],
    ['what would you like for breakfast?'],
    ['what would you like for tea?']
];


for (i = 0; i<= words.length; i++){
    newWords = words[i].slice(0);
    shuffle(newWords);
    var el = document.getElementById('phrase');
    el.textContent = newWords.join(' '); 
    var form = document.getElementById('myform');
    form.addEventListener('submit', checkAnswer(i), false); }

function checkAnswer(i){ 
    return function(){
    var elMsg = document.getElementById('feedback');
    if (document.myForm.textinput.value == correctInput[i]){
        elMsg.textContent= "right answer";}
    else {
        elMsg.textContent= "wrong answer";} 
   }}

function shuffle(newWords) {
    var counter = newWords.length, temp, index;
    while (counter > 0) {
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);
        counter--;
        temp = newWords[counter];
        newWords[counter] = newWords[index];
        newWords[index] = temp;}
    return newWords;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title>  
</head> 
<body>  
    <form  name="myForm" id ="myform">
        <div id ="phrase"></div> 
        <input type = "text" id = "textinput"> 
        <button id="myBtn">Click here</button>
        <div id ="feedback"></div>
    </form>
    <script src = "phraseScrambler.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your problem is not one of closure, but that you overwrite `newWords` as well as the dom content every time, so only the last content stays in the dom. How should it look correctly?

Comment: Thx can you clarify further plz

Comment: First I need to know what you are trying to achieve in the first place. What is the behaviour your expect your code to have and how should the page look?

Comment: The first array should appear (0), after user input, the second array and so on in ascending  sequence. The program jumbles up phrases and the user types the phrase in correct sequence.

Comment: Then you need to rethink your logic. Maybe remove the forloop, put the contents of the forloop into a function, eg. `function displayQuestion(index)` and then call the function with the updated index, every time the user finishes the challenge.

Comment: Check out the answer below.

Comment: Thx the first array(0) starts at runtime but the next array still doesn't run even if user types in correct sequence, 'how are you today?'

Comment: Have you tested the answer below? When you click on `Run code snippet` it works for me.

Comment: Yeah I enter, how are you today?, and I get wrong answer. I'm running it from my android phone but it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I changed to code slightly, try it now

Answer (score 0):

For Actual Arrays

(See "For Array-Like Objects" below for array-like objects.)

You currently have three options and will soon have two more:

```
Use forEach and related (ES5+)
Use a simple for loop
Use for-in correctly
Use for-of (use an iterator implicitly) (ES6+)
Use an iterator explicitly (ES6+)
```

Details:
1. Use forEach and related

If you're using an environment that supports the Array features of ECMAScript5 (directly or using a shim), you can use the new forEach function:

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
a.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are looping through all your items and replacing the text content with the current item: `el.textContent = newWords.join(' ');`
So when it runs through, it is:

1. how are you today?
2. what would you like for breakfast?
3. what would you like for tea?

And since the third is the last run, the value of `el.textContent` stays. So instead of running the for-loop on page load, put your new question generation into a function, eg. `showQuestion` and run it once to start the game.

Then, if the user guesses the right answer, show the next question. To keep track of the current question, you could a variable, eg. `currentQuestion`.

Also, you shouldn't bind a new event listener to the submit button every time you have show a new question. Just do it on setup, eg. with a function called `setup`.

```js
var currentQuestion = 0;

var words = 
        [
    ['how', 'are', 'you', 'today?'],
    ['what', 'would', 'you', 'like', 'for', 'breakfast?'],
    ['what', 'would', 'you', 'like', 'for', 'tea?']
];

var correctInput = [
    ['how are you today?'],
    ['what would you like for breakfast?'],
    ['what would you like for tea?']
];


function showQuestion(i) {
    if(i < words.length) {
        document.myForm.textinput.value = '';
        newWords = words[i].slice(0);
        shuffle(newWords);
        var el = document.getElementById('phrase');
        el.textContent = newWords.join(' ');
    }
}

function setup() {
    showQuestion(currentQuestion);
    var form = document.getElementById('myform');
    form.addEventListener('submit', checkAnswer, false);
}

function checkAnswer(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var elMsg = document.getElementById('feedback');
    if (document.myForm.textinput.value == correctInput[currentQuestion]) {
            elMsg.textContent= "right answer";
            currentQuestion++;
            showQuestion(currentQuestion);
    } else {
        elMsg.textContent= "wrong answer";
    } 
}

function shuffle(newWords) {
    var counter = newWords.length, temp, index;
    while (counter > 0) {
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);
        counter--;
        temp = newWords[counter];
        newWords[counter] = newWords[index];
        newWords[index] = temp;}
    return newWords;}

setup();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title>  
</head> 
<body>  
    <form  name="myForm" id ="myform">
        <div id ="phrase"></div>    
        <input type = "text" id = "textinput"> 
        <button id="myBtn">Click here</button>
        <div id ="feedback"></div>
    </form>
    <script src = "phraseScrambler.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce your error... can you have a look if this happens to you on desktop as well?

Comment: Sure I'll do that, I was thinking  maybe, myForm.textinput.value = ", could have been problem. But, sure I'll check it out on desktop.

Comment: Thx it works fine on desktop. I'm just surprised why a for loop couldn't execute this code efficiently.

Comment: So the eventlistener regardless of whether it is in current running code or in a function that has yet to be executed, it constantly listens for the user to press the button on the html form?

Comment: **Eventlistener**: Yes exactly, once it is bound, it is always listening, unless you unbind it. But if it is in a funtion that has not yet executed, it hasn't been bound yet. **For-loop**: It is just the wrong logical construct for this task, as it runs through all questions at once instead of waiting for the user input.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help, appreciated.